# Detecting if font family changes and showing the dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, css

i have written a HTML code

i am using custom font(gotham.otf) in my CSS element and I want to detect if the html is loading with my custom font or not.  If html is not loading with my custom font I have to show the custom dialog.

```
 <body onload="myFunction()">
 <script>
 function myFunction()
  {
   Here I have to check whether browser is loading with custom font or not,If not show a dialog 
 confirm("Custom font may not work for some browsers!");
  }
  </script> 
  </body>
```

If this is not possible by this way please suggest me the better way to achieve It.

Help is always appreciated, 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Modernizr : http://modernizr.com/ should be able to detect that

Comment: Thanks,but I cant use any third party libraries/files. Is it possible to achieve this using Detector in javascript? and I am using HTML not HTML5.